Conditional Variance for a mixture distribution
I have a confidence-weighted posterior distribution which is a normal mixture:
$\boldsymbol{r}_c = I_{1-c}(U)\boldsymbol{r} + I_c(U)\boldsymbol{r}^t$
· : the confidence level. ∈[0,1].
· : a uniform random variable.
· $I_c$, $I_{1-c}$: indicator functions of non-overlapping intervals of size  and 1−.
now I want to compute its mean and variance. $\boldsymbol{r}$ and $\boldsymbol{r}^t$ has mean $\mu$, $\mu^t$ and variance $\Sigma$, $\Sigma^t$ respectively. I got the mean which is
$E(r_c) = (1-c)\mu + c\mu^t$
but how can I compute the Variance $Var[r_c]$ ? my colleague derived a version based on total law of variance and the definition of variance, the result is $Var[r_]= (1-c)\Sigma + c\Sigma^t + c(1-c)(\mu-\mu^t)(\mu-\mu^t)^T$.
can someone please let me know how that is derived and checked that's correct or not? Thanks!

Not distribution-theory. Changing tag to probability-distributions.

I am presuming that $c$ partitions $[0,1]$ into $\{[0,c),[c,1]\}$ and the indicator functions are meant to correspond to each part, making $I_{1-c}(U)=1-I_c(U)$
Let $B=I_c(U)$, then $B\sim\mathcal{Bern}(c)$ so using the Law of Total Expectation (LoTE) and the properties of a Bernoulli distribution:
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{E}(\mathbf r_c) &= \mathsf{E}((1-B)\mathbf r+B\mathbf r^t)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf E((1-B)\mathbf r+B\mathbf r^t\mid B))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E((1-B)\,\mathsf E(\mathbf r\mid B)+B~\mathsf E(\mathbf r^t\mid B))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E((1-B)\mu) +\mathsf E(B\mu^t)&&\text{due to independence}\\[1ex]&= (1-c)\mu+c\mu^t\end{align}$
As you obtained.
Likewise using the Law of Total Variance (LoTV):
$\qquad\begin{align}\mathsf{Var}(\mathbf r_c) &= \mathsf{Var}((1-B)\mathbf r+B\mathbf r^t)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathsf{Var}((1-B)\mathbf r+B\mathbf r^t\mid B))+\mathsf{Var}(\mathsf E((1-B)\mathbf r+B\mathbf r^t\mid B))\\&~~\vdots\\[1ex]&=(1-c)\Sigma+c\Sigma^t+ c(1-c)~(\mu^t-\mu)(\mu^t-\mu)^\intercal\end{align}$
Just fill in the missing steps, similar to the LoTE example.
